# При отправки заголовок в socket.io возникает проблема, как исправит?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

код

```
const socket = io('http://localhost:3000',{
  query: {
    name: 'Клиент 1'
    // token: 'blablatoken'
  },
  transportOptions: {
    polling: {
      extraHeaders: {
        'x-clientToken': '5434543534364009blablatoken'
      }
    }
  }
});
```

вернет ошибка

```
Request URL: http://localhost:3000/socket.io/?name=%D0%9A%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%201&EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MFfoZYm
Request Method: OPTIONS
Status Code: 400 Bad Request
```

и в ответе

```
{"code":2,"message":"Bad handshake method"}
```

и нету заголовок Cookie: io=uhcjDl0e_nz60VeJAAAA. 
а если уберу добавка заголовок(extraHeaders) то все работает нормально.

```
Request URL: http://localhost:3000/socket.io/?name=%D0%9A%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%201&EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MFfq8Dn
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 OK
```

и есть в хедер Cookie: io=uhcjDl0e_nz60VeJAAAA
В чем проблема? чего я пропустил?

Comment: Похоже на то что при приветственном запросе у тебя слишком большое тело запроса, вот сервер 400 и возвращает.

Comment: спасибо....уже решил проблему

Answer (score 0):

решил так(может и не правильно)

поменял

```
transportOptions: {
    polling: {
      extraHeaders: {
        'x-clientToken': '5434543534364009blablatoken'
      }
    }
  }
```

на

```
extraHeaders: {
  'x-clientToken': '5434543534364009blablatoken'
}
```

а может быт я не то понял но там в оф.сайте был такой [пример](https://socket.io/docs/client-api/#with-extraheaders) отправка хедера